# Where is the backtick on iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

When I type on iOS keyboard, I don't find the backtick (`) character. Where is it located? If there isn't, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch from `ABC` to `123` & then press & hold apostrophe.
Backtick will be the left-most option in the pop-up.

I surprised myself by being able to actually screenshot it…

[image]

Comment: How do you do this if your keyboard turns into the cursor touchpad when you hold a key?

Comment: Oh I figured it out, I have 3D touch on and I was pressing too hard. If I lightly hold it works.